# Error: Conversion from derived* to base&

Tags: c++, inheritance

Although I made the members of both base and derived classes `public`, Why does the conversion says that it is inaccessible?

```
class B 
{
public:
   int var;
};


class D: private B
{
public:
   int var;
};


int main()
{
   D d;
   Base &b = d; //my error
}
```

Comment: You can't with private inheritance. Nobody can tell that D is derived from a B (as it is private). Note: Your last line uses Base not B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert from a derived class to a non-public base class (well, outside the class itself anyway). Private inheritance is typically used as a form of composition, not for substitution so there's no need to convert to the base. In your case it looks like you want substitution so you should use public inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

class B 
{
public:
   int var;
};


class D: public B
{
public:
   int var;
};


int main()
{
   D d;
   B &b = d; //my error
}
```

What you are trying to do won't work with private inheritance. Also note that your base class is known as `B` and not `Base`.

Regards,
Dennis M.